# How to access a singleton and name it in java?

Tags: java, spring, naming-conventions

I want to create a singleton in Java that requires reading from a file configuration to instanciate, amongst other logic (so it's not just a new MySingletonObject()).

What's the proper way to achieve that in Spring ? I was wondering if I should do the following:

```
public interface MySingletonObjectAccessor {
  MySingletonObject getInstance();
}

@Service
public class MySingletonObjectAccessorImpl implements MySingletonObjectAccessor {
  private MySingletonObject mySingletonObject;
  @Override
  public MySingletonObject getInstance() {
    return mySingletonObject;
  }

  MySingletonObjectAccessorImpl() {
    this.MySingletonObject = // complex logic here, that includes reading from a config file

  }
}
```

the usage would then be:

```
@Autowired
MySingletonObjectAccessor msoa;

MySingletonObject mso = msoa.getInstance();
```

Am I on the right track ? If so, what would be the correct naming convention for the MySingletonObjectAccessor service ?

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-bean-scopes/#singleton

Comment: It looks like it would make more sense for your singleton to be a bean of the Spring context directly (Spring beans usually are all singletons too after all). You could have a \@Configuration class that provides a \@Bean-annotated method that builds the singleton.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen so would you recommend avoiding creating a service and an interface?

Comment: Why does it "require reading from a file"? _Usually_, the idea is to put that configuration into Spring itself (and requiring a constructor or builder to read a file makes your code overly coupled).

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I'm using an external library that reads its configuration through an xml file. I want to be able to use that library everywhere in the code, without having to do `new Library("xmlFilePath")` everywhere. Does that make sense ?

Comment: @kumesana can you please provide a code sample with your idea in practice ?

Comment: See Shafiul's answer

Comment: Is it exactly what you meant ? I'm not familiar with @Configuration

Comment: Okay I made my own answer with a full class

Comment: Okay, if it's an external library there's not much you can do. Be aware that it is _extremely_ poor design on their part, and use the `@Bean` suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a public Configuration class like this in your Spring-scanned packages:

```
@Configuration
public class MySingletonProvider {

  @Bean
  public MySingleton nameTheMethodExactlyLikeTheBeanNameYouWant(@Value("${singleton.xml.file}") String xmlConfigFile) {
    Library lib = new Library(xmlConfigFile);
    return new MySingleton(lib);
  }
}
```

Comment: That you very much for this answer, which seems to be what I'm looking for. Just to make sure, 'Provider' is better than 'Accessor' or 'Builder' or 'Factory' or 'Service' or whatever else ?

Comment: @gus.jz I'm honestly not aware of a widely adopted naming convention. Take something that seems to describe well what this Configuration class does for you

Comment: And what about the package name ? Assuming it starts with com.corp.project ?

Comment: And instead of returning MySingleton, if that suits me, I can directly return lib, right ? Library would still only be instanciated once ?

Comment: @gus.jz doesn't matter as long as it is within the packages you told Spring to scan. It's usually in the same package as the services that use the bean, unless your configuration becomes very complicated with multiple classes

Comment: @gus.jz you can return any kind of object. Unless given a scope that isn't singleton, this method will only be called once, and therefore the object only built once.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a Bean and add a scope to make it singleton.

```
    @Configuration
    class MySingletonBeanConfiguration {

      //default is singleton scope
      @Bean
      public MySingletonBean mySingletonBean() {
        return new MySingletonBean();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Technically, beans are singletons unless you specify another scope

Comment: In what class is this in ? And more importantly, I was also very much interested in the naming conventions.

Comment: You can create bean in a config class, see my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using singleton as config then use `@Component` and use `@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)` for singleton.

If it is configuring a file the use FileConfig as class name, as per java standards class name must specify the what it have and what it can do. Ex:- FileReadConfig, FileUploadConfig, DBConnectConfig, EagerInitializedSingleton, StaticBlockSingleton, EnumSingleton ....,

Example:-

```java
@Configuration
public class MySingletonObject {
   private MySingletonObject mySingletonObject;
   public static final String FILENAME = "/Users/xxx/Projects/xxx/config.xml";
   private XMLObject config = null;

    private boolean loadConfig(String fileName) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        String line;
        String content = "";

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                content += line;
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * IF there is no content, the file must not be valid
         */
        if (content.length() <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        this.config = new XMLObject(content);

        return true;
    }
    private Configuration() {
        boolean result = this.loadConfig(FILENAME);

        if (!result) {
            if (!this.createConfig(FILENAME)) {
                System.exit(0); //Catastrophic
            }
        }else{
            mySingletonObject = new MySingletonObject ();
        }
    }

   @Bean("mySingletonObject")
   @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
   public MySingletonObject getMySingletonObject () {
      return mySingletonObject;
   }
}
```

Now

```java
@Autowired
MySingletonObject msoa;
```

Comment: Beans are singletons unless you specify otherwise

Comment: MySingletonObject in my case is an external library. It reads from an xml file, and I want to instanciate it only once: `new MySingletonObject("xmlFilePath")`. Can you please update your code with that in mind ?

Comment: @gus.jz it is instantiated only once. Add all the parameters you want in the constructor.

Comment: @gus.jz, once refer the link https://gist.github.com/kimmellj/bd97790d66c5fd1408e0. I will update my code